# Attempting to gain r/w access to android /system

Tags: android, shell, system, root

Working on a root script for the Nexus 4 with the latest stock rom .img for google (occam) and I have the following code snippet:

```
./adb wait-for-device
echo "remounting system"
./adb shell "mount -o remount,rw /system"
./adb push su /system/bin/
echo "pushing super user"
./adb push Superuser.apk /system/app/
echo "pushing busybox"
./adb push busybox /system/xbin/
./adb shell "chmod 06755 /system/bin/su"
./adb shell "chmod 0644 /system/app/Superuser.apk"
./adb shell "chmod 04755 /system/xbin/busybox"
./adb shell "cd /system/xbin"
./adb shell "busybox --install /system/xbin/"
```

I keep getting the error

```
mount: Operation not permitted
failed to copy 'su' to '/system/bin//su': Read-only file system
pushing super user
failed to copy 'Superuser.apk' to '/system/app//Superuser.apk': Read-only file system
pushing busybox
failed to copy 'busybox' to '/system/xbin//busybox': Read-only file system
Unable to chmod /system/bin/su: No such file or directory
Unable to chmod /system/app/Superuser.apk: No such file or directory
Unable to chmod /system/xbin/busybox: No such file or directory
/system/bin/sh: busybox: not found
```

I've tried using multiple methods of obtaining r/w access, but nothing seems to be working. I have to automate this process due to the fact that other people will use the script so it needs to be automation friendly, but I just can't figure this out.

I've also tried the

```
#su
#mount
#mount | grep system
```

followed by inputting the partition with the system mount and changing it to r/w access, but that also hasn't worked.

Really frustrated at this point. Can anyone help?

Comment: Stupid question, but is your device rooted? You can't access `SU` unless the device is rooted and you need that to `mount`

Comment: No, not rooted. That's what I'm attempting to do here. But what I'm running into is I can't push any files to root the device to the /system folder without write permissions.

Maybe I'm completely wrong on this as well, still pretty new to shell scripting and adb.

Comment: My understanding has always been that when you root a phone, a new image is pushed onto the phone which effectively adds the `su` executable as well as adds code that checks for su permissions when an app attempted to access su permissions. I would start by downloads the Android source, compiling and pushing it on a test device (like Panda board) then try to figure out how to push `su` executable onto it. Then perhaps make an image for the Nexus 4 and push it on the phone. I could also be completely wrong here..

Comment: If your device is not rooted, then you cannot do priveleged operations without finding and exploiting some security mistake in the existing software.  Fundamentally, you are trying to do something which is not supposed to be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Ali. I believe that is the issue. The previous image I had was a stock rom, but had been put out as part of a root method. It stopped working, and I guess I didn't know that `su` had to be part of the new image I was putting together.

Comment: @Bebop_ - since you've logged in recently, please return to this apparently abandoned question and either accept the answer which points out that your goal is unrealizable by this means, or else delete the question.

Comment: Nexus devices can be rooted without any exploits, but you have to unlock the bootloader which means wiping all data. You can just use [CF-Auto-Root](http://autoroot.chainfire.eu).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It gives the error because you aren't root. The system partition is mounted read-only. You can try to push the binary to /data/local/tmp. Then you can make su executable and eventual run it. But it doesn't mean you can have root. To become root you need to push an exploit like psneuter to /data/local/tmp and run it. It crashes the shell and reopen a new one with root rights. Then you can remount the system-partition read-write and install su.

Answer (score 1):

Try the commands below

```
adb shell "su -c mount -o remount,rw /system"
adb shell "su -c chmod 06755 /system/bin/su"
```

and so on.